# Avoid using multiple loops in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have the following arrays to update at each call of the `update` action:

```
params['traject_names'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.traject_names[i] = v
  end
  params['used_vehicles'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.used_vehicles[i] = v
  end
  params['nb_kms'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.nb_kms[i] = v
  end    
  params['parkings'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.parkings[i] = v
  end    
  params['trains'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.trains[i] = v
  end    
  params['taxis'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.taxis[i] = v
  end    
  params['metros'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.metros[i] = v
  end
  params['meals'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.meals[i] = v
  end
  params['hotels'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.hotels[i] = v
  end
  params['natures'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.natures[i] = v
  end
  params['amounts'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.amounts[i] = v
  end
  params['o_ns'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.o_ns[i] = v
  end
  params['clients'].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.clients[i] = v
  end
```

As you can see, it's dirty and repetitive. What could be a way to make this much smaller?

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
['trajects_names', 'used_vehicles', 'nb_kms', etc.].each do |n|
   params[n].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.n[i] = v
   end
end
```

However I don't know how to access the `@expense` variable through `n`. Any ideas?

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

```
['traject_names', 'nb_kms'].each do |n|
  params[n].each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.send(n)[i] = v
  end
end
```

I just added `params` to @vape's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) method to do this:

```
['trajects_names', 'used_vehicles', 'nb_kms', etc.].each do |n|
   n.each_with_index do |v, i|
    @expense.send(n)[i] = v
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting a `undefined method `[]=' for 0:Fixnum` at the `send` line.

Comment: which key are you getting it for? what is the type of that property?

Comment: I mean you know what properties the `@expense` object has. If not all of its properties are lists, then obviously running `@expense.send(n)[i]` could raise an error since the `[]` operator will not be defined for some of the properties. You can fix that depending on the property but the fact remains that the solution to your problem is the `Object#send` method.

Comment: All of them are arrays. Example: params["traject_names"] = ["text", "text"]

Comment: If all of them were arrays, then all of them would have the `[]` method defined and no error would be raised. The error is clear. You are using the `[]` operator on an object (a Fixnum in this case) which does not support it. Please make sure that *all* of the properties you're referencing are arrays.